# My app crashes when I hit log out

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that allows me to log in and out. the log out button now seems to crash the app when i press it when it was working ok before. It still logs out the user and when you go back into the app you have to sign in again.

I have added my whole on create method below where the action happens at the bottom. Just incase i have added a duplicate or something that i am missing

```
 //view objects
    private TextView textViewUserEmail;
    private Button buttonLogout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        buttonAddProducts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddProducts);
        buttonAddBeverages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddBeverages);
        buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonAddBeverages.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference currentUserReference = databaseUsers.child(uid);
        currentUserReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot userSnapshot) {
                if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
                    User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    if(user.getAdminUser() == true)
                    {
                        buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        buttonAddBeverages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Log.i("myInfoTag", "Connection problem");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore exceptions
            }
        });


        //if the user is not logged in
        //that means current user will return null
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            //closing this activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

        //getting current user
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //initializing views
        textViewUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);


        //displaying logged in user name
        textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome "+user.getEmail());


        buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //logging out the user
                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                //closing activity
                finish();
                //starting login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }
```

When i press log out it just crashes with the msg beer app has stopped

Comment: are you going to tell us what the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following block of code does not cause an immediate transfer of execution to the started activity.  It only initiates that flow, and execution continues to the following statements.

```
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        //closing this activity
        finish();
        //starting login activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
```

In your case, one of the following statements is `user.getEmail()`, which will throw a `NullPointerException` when there is no user signed in.